# Struggling with Python extrapolation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, extrapolation

I have a recorded data from lab equipment. In several cases I would like to interpolate and extrapolate from recorded data.

I will be using `I_id` and `I_iq` as my main control variables.

I have tried many different variations to get this working but I cannot.

My data looks like this for the first piece of measurement equipment:

```py
I_id = [0,-25,-50,-75,-100,-125,-150,-175,0,-25,-50,-75,-100,-125,-150,-175,0,-25,-50,-75,-100,-125,-150,-175,0,-25,-50,-75,-100,-125,-150,-175,0,-25,-50,-75,-100,-125,-150,0,-25,-50,-75,-100,-125,-150,0,-25,-50,-75,-100,-125,0,-25,-50,-75,0,0,-25,-50,-75,-100,-125,-150,-175]
I_iq = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,75,75,75,75,75,75,75,75,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,125,125,125,125,125,125,125,150,150,150,150,150,150,175,175,175,175,200,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
var = [-0.040032,0.011188,0.030851,0.183906,0.258842,0.355956,0.560895,0.753436,3.325974,11.611581,12.113206,12.804795,13.11953,13.423358,13.689702,13.899162,17.267299,23.553225,24.495611,25.086743,25.559352,25.953261,26.248565,26.534781,34.935503,35.761774,36.52968,37.227405,37.834295,38.310515,38.715564,38.944562,46.322635,47.382142,48.31467,49.163737,49.897316,50.510074,50.936424,57.367325,58.686137,59.86712,60.871714,61.727998,62.407764,62.902043,68.254704,69.745637,71.075856,72.232987,73.282945,74.110145,78.724496,80.425047,81.965227,83.270788,88.79109,69.950271,1.538601,0.005484,0.160758,0.336944,0.44188,0.568149,0.825262]
```

| **I_id** | **I_iq** | **var** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | -25 | 0 |
| 2 | -50 | 0 |
| 3 | -75 | 0 |
| 4 | -100 | 0 |
| 5 | -125 | 0 |
| 6 | -150 | 0 |
| 7 | -175 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 | 25 |
| 9 | -25 | 25 |
| 10 | -50 | 25 |
| 11 | -75 | 25 |
| 12 | -100 | 25 |
| 13 | -125 | 25 |
| 14 | -150 | 25 |
| 15 | -175 | 25 |
| 16 | 0 | 50 |
| 17 | -25 | 50 |
| 18 | -50 | 50 |
| 19 | -75 | 50 |
| 20 | -100 | 50 |
| 21 | -125 | 50 |
| 22 | -150 | 50 |
| 23 | -175 | 50 |
| 24 | 0 | 75 |
| 25 | -25 | 75 |
| 26 | -50 | 75 |
| 27 | -75 | 75 |
| 28 | -100 | 75 |
| 29 | -125 | 75 |
| 30 | -150 | 75 |
| 31 | -175 | 75 |
| 32 | 0 | 100 |
| 33 | -25 | 100 |
| 34 | -50 | 100 |
| 35 | -75 | 100 |
| 36 | -100 | 100 |
| 37 | -125 | 100 |
| 38 | -150 | 100 |
| 39 | 0 | 125 |
| 40 | -25 | 125 |
| 41 | -50 | 125 |
| 42 | -75 | 125 |
| 43 | -100 | 125 |
| 44 | -125 | 125 |
| 45 | -150 | 125 |
| 46 | 0 | 150 |
| 47 | -25 | 150 |
| 48 | -50 | 150 |
| 49 | -75 | 150 |
| 50 | -100 | 150 |
| 51 | -125 | 150 |
| 52 | 0 | 175 |
| 53 | -25 | 175 |
| 54 | -50 | 175 |
| 55 | -75 | 175 |
| 56 | 0 | 200 |
| 57 | 0 | 0 |
| 58 | -25 | 0 |
| 59 | -50 | 0 |
| 60 | -75 | 0 |
| 61 | -100 | 0 |
| 62 | -125 | 0 |
| 63 | -150 | 0 |
| 64 | -175 | 0 |

I have tried creating a `meshgrid`:

```py
for var in target_variables:

    x = idq_data["Id"]
    y = idq_data["Iq"]
    z = idq_data[var]
    
    # Create a grid of data for the target variables
    xi = np.arange(np.min(x), np.max(x), 1)
    yi = np.arange(np.min(y), np.max(y), 1)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

    # Interpolation function using gridata
    zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xx, yy), method='cubic')
```

However, when using `griddata` when I plot the extrapolated points do not exist.

```py
    # plot the interpolated data on a contour plot
    fig = go.Figure()
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Contour(
        x=xi,
        y=yi,
        z=zi,
        colorscale='Jet',
    ))
    
    fig.show()
```

[image: Contour Plot]

I understand they have not been plotted as they are `NaN`'s but why has the values not been extrapolated?

Comment: Extrapolated for what values of your independent variables?

Comment: Is the purpose of your interpolation and extrapolation only for plotting, or something else?

Comment: I'm looking to get the value of var for each I_I'd and I_iq point. Not just plotting but several calculations will be done afterwards on the new data

Comment: ...fine, but that isn't interpolation. That's simply lookup, if you're pulling data on top of an already-defined point.

Comment: But the data currently has steps of 25 for I'd and Iq , it would need interpolated to get steps of 1? Then as there is missing data from outside the test area say when id is -175 and Iq is 175, the corresponding value in the var column would need extrapolated? Unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: So when you say _each Id and Iq point_, you don't mean the points in your original data - you mean the points in your new grid.

Comment: Yes, I should of named them better.

Comment: Your data are highly linear everywhere except close to 0. I do not think that a generic extrapolator like Radial Basis will produce any sensible results. I recommend that you perform linear regression on IQ, ignoring all data for ID > -20.

Answer (score 0):

You can tinker with the parameters of the Radial Basis method:

```py
xi = np.arange(I_id.min(), 1+I_id.max())
yi = np.arange(I_iq.min(), 1+I_iq.max())
xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

interpolator = scipy.interpolate.RBFInterpolator(
    y=np.stack((I_id, I_iq), axis=1),
    d=var,
    smoothing=0.1,
)
zi = interpolator(np.stack((xgrid, ygrid)).reshape((-1, 2))).reshape(xgrid.shape)
```

but it doesn't work very well. Instead I will recommend a linear regression over (most of) your data:

```py
'''
[ Id Iq 1 ] [ a ] = [ var ]
[ Id Iq 1 ] [ b ]   [ var ]
[ ...   1 ] [ c ]   [ ... ]
'''
linear_region = I_id <= -25
affine = np.stack((I_id, I_iq, np.ones_like(I_id)), axis=1)[linear_region, :]
params, *_ = np.linalg.lstsq(affine, var[linear_region])
print(params)

di = np.arange(I_id.min(), 1+I_id.max())[np.newaxis, :]
qi = np.arange(I_iq.min(), 1+I_iq.max())[:, np.newaxis]
vi = params[0]*di + params[1]*qi + params[2]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
graph: matplotlib.contour.QuadContourSet = ax.contourf(di.ravel(), qi.ravel(), vi)
bar: matplotlib.colorbar.Colorbar = fig.colorbar(graph)
bar.set_label('var')
ax.set_xlabel('I_id')
ax.set_ylabel('I_iq')
plt.show()
```

producing planar parameters

```
[-0.01984498  0.47951953 -1.0313259 ]
```

[image: graph]

Don't use the jet colormap.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, however when I look at the original data plotted over the top on by plotting the inter/extrap data on a surface and the original on a 3dscatter. there seems to be discrepancies between the original data and the interp/extrap data. Also Im still confused how the "built-in" functions seem to fail to work (probably how im using them). For example, when just trying to extrapolate using the linear method it just uses the nearest value: [linear](https://imgur.com/a/CIZlvKh)

Comment: Small discrepancies from the original are expected for linear regression.